# Tweaking the Loss before the Optimizer Step

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

I want to add an extra operation before running the `AdamOptimizer` operation on my `loss`, so as to help the model deal with repetitions in my data. The relevant code snippet looks something like this:

```py
loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=predLogits, labels=actLabels)
loss = tf.reshape(loss, [batchsize, -1])
repMask = tf.sqrt(tf.cast(tf.abs(tf.subtract(tf.cast(Y, tf.int64), tf.cast(X, tf.int64))), tf.float32))
lossPost = loss - repMask
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(LR).minimize(lossPost)
```

So, in other words, instead of minimizing `loss`, I want `AdamOptimizer` to minimize its slightly tweaked version, which is `lossPost`. I then train the model in the usual way:

```py
_ = sess.run([train_step], feed_dict=feed_dict)
```

I noticed that adding this workaround of minimizing `lossPost` instead of `loss` has no impact on the accuracy of the model. The model produces the exact same output with or without this workaround. It seems that it continues to optimize the original, unmodified `loss`. Why is this the case?

My original approach was to perform this tweak at the `softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` step, by using the `weighted_cross_entropy_with_logits` instead, but I have an extra complication there, since there is an extra dimension of Vocabulary (this is a character-level-style model). So I thought it would be easier to do this afterwords, and as long as it's done prior to the optimization step it should be doable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your model it seems like `X` and `Y` are constants (that is, they depend only on the data). In this case `repMask` is also constant, as it is defined by

```
repMask = tf.sqrt(tf.cast(tf.abs(tf.subtract(tf.cast(Y, tf.int64), tf.cast(X, tf.int64))), tf.float32))
```

Hence `loss` and `lossPost` differ by constant value, and this has no effect on the minimization process (it is like finding `x` that minimizes `x^2-1` vs `x` that minimizes `x^2-5`. Both `x` are the same).

Comment: X and Y are the input values and the predicted values at each training step. So the idea of the experiment is to adjust the loss for instances where the model predicts values that are the same as the input values (because I have many repetitions in the data). So where they are the same, X-Y is zero, and adjustment is zero, while elsewhere that adjustment is positive (to make loss smaller). So i guess the question becomes, by the time a Y is predicted at each step, is it then too late to optimize at that step?

Comment: Or I guess you mean X and Y are constants from the perspective of the optimizer, since they are external to the optimization at each step?

Comment: Yes this is what I meant. Now since lossPost is a vector and not a number, you can try to add the following line to your code: lossPost=tf.reduce_mean(lossPost) (since lossPost is a vector, it makes more sence to minimize the sum of the squares of its values). However, I am not sure that this approach makes sence (when dealing with repetitions). Your loss vector from the first line in your code and repMask vector are quite different quantities with different units.